# ASP.net, PHP and Retrofit for Android

Tags: php, android, asp.net, iis, retrofit2

Can you use ASP.net with retrofit? I'm currently using PHP but might migrate to ASP.net. Any info or advise would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The network libraries used in android(retrofit, volley etc) are not dependent on any server side languages like asp.net, php etc.

> *Can you use ASP.net with retrofit?*

*Yes you can use ASP.net with retrofit*

By the way retrofit, like any other network libraries run on the client side and hence has no association with backend technology

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! Didn't really understood what rest is until now.

Answer (score 1):

So let me tell you what REst Api is.
It is known as REpresentational State Transfer. Which means that when you use MVC framework, the MVC framework is stateless and it gets data from Rest Api. This is the benefit of using MVC. On retrofit you are doing the same work i.e making an Okhttp connection which helps you to communicate with url of backend. Then backend processes data and gives you the response back. Thats why the  backend does not matter whatever you do from. 
Happy Coding!

Comment: Thanks! Will definitely research more on MVC.